# Unable to Work With Attribute Painter in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add features to a simple point file and assign attributes based on a field using Attribute Painter. I am able to choose the source feature and the field but when I add a point the attribute dialogue appears and I have to fill it manually. Is there a way to have the features assigned the correct field attribute without manually filling out the dialogue?

I'm rather new to QGIS.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this plugin is for 'painting' attributes on existing features, rather than adding features with pre-defined attributes.

So you would have to create the features without attributes first, ignoring the 'edit feature form' that is popping up, then apply the attributes to the new features after you have selected them (can be done in bulk by selecting multiple features).

You can turn off the pop up by going to Settings > Options > Digitizing > check the option to 'suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation'

Comment: How can I make the edit attributes form stop popping up?

Comment: You can turn off the pop up by going to Settings > Options > Digitizing > check the option to 'suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation'

Comment: That is what I was looking for.